# RecyclerView, slow scrollToPosition, setSelected

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview

Prompt, faced with scrollToPosition speed. I RecyclerView 900 positions and need to quickly establish a position as scrollToPosition very slow, c ListView such problems were not setSelection working out perfectly. It is possible to accelerate the scrollToPosition?

```
public class EventAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<EventAdapter.Holder> {

final static public String TAG = "EventAdapter";

Context context;
List<Event> items;

public EventAdapter(List<Event> items) {
    this.items = items;
}

@Override
public EventAdapter.Holder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_list_event, parent, false);
    context = parent.getContext();
    return new EventAdapter.Holder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(EventAdapter.Holder holder, int position) {
    holder.setModel(context, items.get(position), position);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return items.size();
}

public class Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public View block;

    Holder(View view) {
        super(view);
            block = (View) view.findViewById(R.id.cv);
        }

        public void setModel(Context context, Event model, int position) {

        }
    }
}

LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
rv.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
rv.setHasFixedSize(true);

linearLayoutManager.scrollToPosition(index);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of ways to do it:

1) Try **[smoothScrollToPosition](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager.html#smoothScrollToPosition(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView,%20android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.State,%20int))** as : [will certainly work]

```
Toast.makeText(this, "Scroll...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
myList.smoothScrollToPosition(0);
```

2) Also read about **[scrollToPositionWithOffset](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager.html#scrollToPositionWithOffset(int,%20int))** as this may help too

Comment: smoothScrollToPosition - I try, it's not what you need. You need to quickly set the position without smooth, and scrollToPosition very long this worked.

Comment: @KeyGenQt : The solution worked or not, unable to guess from your response. And if not you still found something or still looking?